# Can I power arduino uno R3 with 9v battery through Vin?

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to power up arduino through Vin port , what should be the input voltage ?

Comment: Here is the answer - https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/39041/powering-an-arduino-with-more-than-5-v/39043#39043

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powering an Arduino with more than 5 V](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/39041/powering-an-arduino-with-more-than-5-v)

Answer (score 1):

About 7.5V to 9V is best. A 9V battery is often not capable to supply enough current for an Arduino. Do you have a multimeter to measure the battery voltage drop when the Arduino is connected ?

Answer (score -1):

Are you really sure? I must search for mine, but what i remember, that over the pins....
ok I looked, sry, Jot was right :D... on the Input Pins, you find three kinds right? 3.3, 5 an Vin, which will be a range of V for sure ;)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/63310)