# How much power can a proto board handle?

Tags: esp8266, power, wires, neopixel, prototype

I have been working on a project where I will be powering an Arduino and some LED light strips (2 x 3 Meter strips w/ 30 LEDs per meter). I am powering all of it from a 5v 10amp power supply.

Currently I have split the power cable and have it running to the board and the LED's in separate runs.

As I move from a breadboard to a more permanent proto-board, it would be great to add a barrel connector onto the proto-board and just have a single plugin for power so I can easily disconnect it.

Will this cause any issues if all of the power comes from the proto-board? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide information about how many LEDs, how long the light strips, and/or the measured current. Your supply can provide 10A, but that has little bearing on what is actually drawn by the system.

Comment: @Tyler Pearce What LED strip type are you using?

Comment: They are WS2812b/Neopixel strips. 2 x 3 Meter strips w/ 30 LEDs per meter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not practical do to that with protoboard of any form.

There are two reasons for this:

1. Barrel jacks are not rated for 10A - I think the most powerful I have seen is 3A.
2. To handle 10A over (for example) 6 inches of track you would require tracks roughly 8mm wide at 1oz copper. No protoboard provides such tracks.

Even if you're only using half the capacity of your power supply (5A) you still exceed a barrel jack, and would need traces about 3mm wide.

Answer (score 1):

A common way to solve this is to solder a wire onto the tracks on the proto-board.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem to have your power source coming from your protoboard to supply your arduino since your protoboard can gives to your arduino one of these possibilities explained [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/39041/powering-an-arduino-with-more-than-5-v/39043#39043).